# Measuring unknown speaker/piezo element

Tags: arduino, speakers, piezo-buzzer

I have an assortment of small speakers/piezo elements and I'd like to connect them to an arduino without damaging either. I don't know what characteristics the elements have or what to look for but I do have a basic multimeter.

What should I measure? How do I know which ones to just discard? Otherwise do I need extra resistors in the way? If so, what values?

[image]

Comment: Many piezo beepers have a transistor oscillator in them so they are not a speaker. A piezo transducer is not a speaker, instead it is a high frequency squeaker.

Answer (score 1):

Piezo elements measure as purely capacitive. If you connect them directly to an Arduino DIO pin then I'd put 100 Ohm resistor in series (to protect the DIO pin).

You cannot damage the piezo element with an Arduino output. If you set up a square wave of 1-2 kHz you may be able to hear them as a basic test, though some require 10s of volts peak to peak to use them at higher volumes.

[Here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Parallax%20PDFs/900-00001_Web.pdf) is a common Piezo speaker that works at 5V p-p to give you some hints on what to expect.

- Rated Current – 1 mA (Max)
- SPL @ 4 kHz/10 cm – 80 db
- Resonant Frequency – 4000 Hz (+/‐ 500)
- Capacitance @ 120 Hz – 13000 pF (+/‐ 30%)
- Operating Temperature – ‐20 to +70 °C

Answer (score 1):

Some piezos will output 50 volts, if tapped or scratched with your finger nail. For a time duration of milliSeconds, and repeating everytime the mechanical energy occurs.

I'd use a 10,000 ohm resistor between the Piezo and the MCU. This helps the MCU's ESD diodes.

Also consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzDfie.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use schottky diodes; they protect the ESD diodes on the MCU silicon.